# twitch chatscraping in jsDom

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, twitch, jsdom

I'm building a universal chatscraper for streaming sites using JSDOM, and twitch.tv  is throwing a typerror  seen below

```
23:57:50 [ERROR] Uncaught error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigationStart' of undefined
    at t.NdhY.e.getCurrentTimestamp (https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/core-45cc951fa1577878dbc1.js:1:419319)
    at t.NdhY.e.resetStartTime (https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/core-45cc951fa1577878dbc1.js:1:419527)
    at t.e (https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/core-45cc951fa1577878dbc1.js:1:413933)
    at new t (https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/core-45cc951fa1577878dbc1.js:1:420474)
    at new e (https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/core-45cc951fa1577878dbc1.js:1:433384)
    at new e (https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/core-45cc951fa1577878dbc1.js:1:108643)
    at ve (https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/core-45cc951fa1577878dbc1.js:1:105431)
    at Object.gg62 (https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/core-45cc951fa1577878dbc1.js:1:879504)
    at c (https://www.twitch.tv/iamfallfromgrace:1:1371)
    at Object.150 (https://static.twitchcdn.net/assets/core-45cc951fa1577878dbc1.js:1:24255)
```

clearly the script on the page is trying to access a property on an object that exists in the browser, but not in JSDOM.

has anyone else encountered this while mounting a streamer page for twitch in JSDOM?  is there anything about the JSDOM config i can change?

thanks.

Comment: Twitch Chat is just an irc server so why not just connect to the irc server?

Comment: I was hoping to not need seperate logic from one site to the next. But I may need to do exactly that if I don't find a way to get js dom up and running